# Django - cant find my static files even after manually correcting the path

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I've encountered a problem that, even after an evening of trying , I've not yet been able to resolve.

For my project I have a single **static** directory, and I've included the css files for the 'login' page in there. Yet when I try to load the webpage I get a 404 error.

When I try to find the files with the 'findstatic' or 'collectstatic' commands the files get skiped. Its like the 'static' directory is invisible to django. I've even directly copies the 'Login' folder to 'static_root', but even then the program was Django was unable to find the files. 
Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

My project folder looks like this:

```
* MPS (main folder)  
      * Scraper (app)
      * Database (app)
      * Templates
      * Static_root
      * Static
          * Login
                * css
                     * style.css
```

My settings.py has been configured like so:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root/')
```

And I call the static files in the template with the following code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
(...)
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'login/css/style.css' %}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project folder structure looks a bit different from most Django projects. Traditionally it would look something more like this:

```
myproject/
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
    settings.py
myapp/
    static/
        myapp/
            css/
                style.css
            js/
                index.js
manage.py
```

Notice that the app static files of `myapp` is within a subfolder called the same as the app folder. This is to easily namespace the files as you can read more about in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/).

> Now we might be able to get away with putting our static files directly in my_app/static/ (rather than creating another my_app subdirectory), but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will use the first static file it finds whose name matches, and if you had a static file with the same name in a different application, Django would be unable to distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the right one, and the easiest way to ensure this is by namespacing them. That is, by putting those static files inside another directory named for the application itself.

Comment: I ended up reverting to the structure suggested in your post and Django was finally able to find the static files. Thanks!